# Function "for" in R with two objectos or vectors

Tags: r, function, for-loop

i'm developing a function to perform operations between two vectors (dataframes, for example), using the function "for":

```
> A <- c(1,2,3)
> B <- c(2)
> result <- c()
> for (i in 1:length(A))
+ {
+   for (j in 1:length(B))
+   {
+     result <- (A*B)
+   }
+ }
> result
[1] 2 4 6
```

However, when I increase the vector "B" to 2 values:

```
> A <- c(1,2,3)
> B <- c(2,4)
```

the function generates

```
Warning messages lost:
"Major object length is not a multiple of the length of a lower one."
> result
[1] 2 8 6
```

So, how i can create a loop that performs the operation against "A" for each row "B"?

Thnaks so much!

Comment: Are you looking for `outer(A, B)`? If you want to operate on data.frames, you should give an example with data.frames and show the expected result.

Comment: Did you mean `result = c(result, A[i] * B[j])`? If so, eventually it would be best to pre-allocate with `result <- numeric( length(A) * length(B) )` and use `result[ (i-1)*length(B) + j] <- A[i] * B[j]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you don't use the variables `i` and `j` but calculate the product `A * B` instead.

You can produce the desired result using `sapply`:

```
A=c(1,2,3); B=c(2,4)

sapply(A, "*", B)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    4    6
# [2,]    4    8   12
```

or matrix multiplication:

```
A %*% t(B)

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    4
# [2,]    4    8
# [3,]    6   12
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, A's length has to be a multiple of B's one : if they have the same length, `A*B`will return a vector of same length whose terms will the multiplications of corresponding elements of A and B `(A[1]*B[1],...A[n]*B[n])`.

If `length(A)=k*length(B)`, k>1, you will get a vector with same length as A with `(A[1]*B[1]...A[l]*B[l],A[l+1]*B[1],A[l+2]*B[2]...A[kl]*B[l])`, where l is B length and therefore kl is A length.

Here, 3 is a multiple of 1 but not of 2, hence the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use `outer`:

```
outer(A, B, FUN='*')
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    4
# [2,]    4    8
# [3,]    6   12
```